# Как отключить активацию меню при нажатии на alt в atom?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, atom

Перешёл с sublime-text на atom. Всё отлично, но меня жутко бесит одна вещь. При переключении раскладки (комбинация `alt+shift`) у меня активируется верхняя строка меню и это не даёт продолжать мне писать код. Я должен нажать `esc`, `alt` или кликнуть в то место, где был курсор, чтобы продолжить писать код.

Я поэкспериментировал и выяснил, что это происходит именно при нажатии на `alt`. Активацию меню можно избежать если использовать `shift+alt` или нажимать кнопки в такой последовательности:
зажать `alt`, зажать `shift`, отпустить `shift`, отпустить `alt`. Это неудобно, не хочу из-за одного приложения переучиваться.

Была у кого-либо похожая проблема? Как вы её решали?

Ubuntu 18.04, atom 1.52.0

Пробовал на Ubuntu 20.04, тоже самое.
Нагуглил, что такая проблема есть во всех приложениях написанных на electron, но как такого решения нет.

На некоторых форумах предлагают различными способами запретить приложению считывать нажатие на `alt`. Мне это не подходит, потому что эта клавиша участвует во многих полезных комбинациях в приложении

Comment: Это не проблема атома. Это особенность винды. Точно такое же когда то было в обычном ворде. а Ctrl+Shift или CapsLock решает проблему в корне.

Comment: @KoVadim так линукс же...

Comment: и в линуксе тоже. Думаю, даже в маках

Comment: @KoVadim с каких пор? Только что проверил - ни в ворде, ни в VSCode (т.е. на электроне) такой проблемы не наблюдается. Притом независимо от порядка нажатия и отпускания клавиш...

Comment: в современном ворде оно вроде не воспроизводится. но на старых (97/2003) доставало очень сильно.

Answer (score 2):

У меня была такая проблема, в итоге переучился на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Можно жать одним пальцем - мизинцем, и выглядеть изящным.

Comment: либо использовать CapsLock.

Comment: Придётся переучиваться, если не будет способов лучше, напрягает только то, что я часто использую ПК других людей (не для работы в atom) во время работы или учёбы и там везде alt+shift

Answer (score 1):

Нужно переопределить/отключить `keybindings` в настройках `Atom`. В данном случае нужно отключить привязку `native!`, заменить на `unset!`.

1. В файле `~/.atom/keymap.cson` пишем:

   ```css
   'body .native-key-bindings':
     'alt-left': 'unset!'
     'alt-right': 'unset!'
   ```
2. Перезапускаем `Atom`.

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, всё так же

Answer (score 0):

В линуксе такая проблема довольно распространённая и касается всех вариантов раскладок.

Есть пара решений этого:

- сменить комбинацию переключения раскладки
- самописный скрипт с использованием `xbindkeysrc`, который будет за систему менять раскладку

Лично мне помог второй вариант, хоть и выглядит это как костыль.

Принцип я взял из  [этой статьи](https://habr.com/ru/post/476996/), не знаю, поможет ли вам.

Comment: Тоже видел этот пост, но я не понимаю как это может помочь. Atom ведёт себя так при нажатии на alt, а не при смене раскладки. Да раскладка будет переключаться другим способом, с помощью скрипта, но atom же всё равно видит нажатие на alt. Что должно поменяться?

Comment: и за системного хоткея, при смене раскладки выпадает `shift` и приложение думает, что нажат только `alt` и соответственно открывает вам меню. в статье системный хоткей снимается, и вешается на кастомный обработчик. получается,  приложение после данных манипуляций должно видеть нажатие `alt + shift`, а я не просто `alt`. фокус теряться не должен. попробуйте, вдруг поможет

Comment: Приложение то видит нажатие на shift, если я нажимаю `shift` при зажатом `alt` и отпускаю `shift` раньше `alt` то меню не активируется. При `shift + alt` тоже не активируется. Тут просто логика приложения, оно все кнопки видит, но так работает. По его мнению, если я первым отпустил alt а не shift, то мне надо меню показать

Answer (score 0):

Долго искал решение и нашел. Решил опубликовать здесь, так как именно эта ветка хорошо выдается в поиске. Решение для Linux, но думаю для Windows аналогично.
Качаем расширение с сайта atom: [menu-editor](https://atom.io/packages/menu-editor) и устанавливаем как сказано на странице загрузки - а именно пишем в терминале:

```
apm install menu-editor
```

(Именно *apm*, это не ошибка) Ждем пока команда отработает, перезапускаем Atom.
Открываем настройки, ищем слева пункт "Menu", раскрываем вкладку "View" и снимаем галку с пункта "Open Reviews Tab". Всё!

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема всех приложений основанных на электроне. В какой-то из версий этот баг появился, несколько лет назад, потом его вроде как пофиксили, а после опять смержили реквест с этой проблемой, достучаться до разработчиков никак не удается, на некоторых приложениях все-таки исправляют, но в атоме я сижу с этой бедой уже не один год. Самый раздражающий эффект это когда привыкаешь к alt+shift, а после появления меню нажимаешь еще раз alt уже не в атоме, а во всех приложениях, это ломает всю работу. Issue на гитхабе атома висит с 2020го https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/21825, а в электроне вообще с 2014 года! https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/474, хотя его и закрыли, но такой эффект снова и снова появляется в некоторых приложениях, подобные issue открываются по нескольку раз во всех github репозиториях связанных с electron.

Answer (score 0):

In `Settings -> Core -> Title bar`
Set value "hidden" (It's disable native bar)
[image: Disable native title bar]

After that Alt should not cause focus reset!

---

To return the bar, use the extension "title-bar-replacer"
[image: package screen]

Go to package settings and uncheck "Alt Gives Focus"

[image: settings general]

### **Ответ на русском:**

Отключите стандартную верхнюю панель через настройки. Это должно избавить от фокусироваки на ней при нажатии <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
`Settings -> Core -> Title Bar`
Установите значение "скрыто".

---

Чтобы вернуть панель установите расширение `title-bar-replacer`. И сразу же отлючите в параметрах этого расширения "Alt Gives Focus"

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык